# LOGON Trigger on All Server Restricting New Logins

Tags: sql-server

```
Create TRIGGER Logon_Trigger_HOST_IP
ON ALL SERVER  FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [master].[dbo].[IP_AND_HOST]
   --the auditing snippet below works fine in a 
  --login trigger, 
  --database trigger 
  --or any stored procedure.
    SELECT 

conn.session_ID as SPID,
conn.client_net_address as IPAddress,
sess.host_name as MachineName,
sess.program_name as ApplicationName,
login_name as LoginName
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn
inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions sess
on conn.session_ID=sess.session_ID

  END
GO
```

By executing the above trigger users are unable to log in; sa or any user getting restricted.

I want to allow all user logins and record their data.
Why it is restricting user login saying `login failed due to trigger...`

Comment: Welcome! Can you please explain to me how this is remotely related to InfoSec? Your question is "Why is it restricting userlogin?" That is certainly not an InfoSec question, this belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: What's the definition for `IP_AND_HOST`? Also, a trigger that fails to reference the *data that caused the trigger to fire*, (here, `EVENTDATA` , for instance), is almost certainly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the Login's, don't have permission to `INSERT` into the table `[master].[dbo].[IP_AND_HOST]`. As a result, the trigger fails and so does the login.

You'll need to either permit `guest` to `INSERT` into the table `[master].[dbo].[IP_AND_HOST]`, or change the Trigger to run under credentials of a user that can using `EXECUTE AS`: [EXECUTE AS Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)